# How to split background color into two using css

Tags: html, css, background

I'm new to css I need to split an HTML page into two background and top of that i need to have text and login form also.can i have sample css and html code

i have tried in css like this

```
.logindiv {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1F4E79 50%, #FFFF 50%);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container logindiv">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="login-panel panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Please Sign In</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-signin" }))
                    {
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

                        <fieldset>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="Username" type="text" autofocus>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" type="password" value="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="Remember Me">Remember Me
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Change this to a button or input when using this as a form <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Login</a> -->

                            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" name="logsubmit" id="logsubmit" type="submit">Login</button>

                        </fieldset>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a get-your-work-done-for-free site. You need to do the work, and only ask questions when you're stuck, showing your existing code, what you expect it to do, and what it actually does.

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this: (I changed the second color from white to grey since you wouldn't see it otherwise on the white background)

```css
.logindiv {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1F4E79 0%, #1F4E79 50%, #ddd 50%, #ddd 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="logindiv"></div>
```